# Trying to Create Factor Variable with labels getting this error message: Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors

Tags: r, dplyr

Im trying to create a new variable, recode it, turn it into a factor variable with new labels. First part of the recode goes OK, but when I try to convert to factor variable it gives me this message: Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors

```
mutate(locale = case_when (V4024 %in% c("R/hme-own dwell",
                                  "R/hme-det bldg","R/home-vac/2nd", 
                                        "R/hme-htl/mtl") ~ 1,
         
          V4024 %in% c("N/hme-own yrd", "N/hme apt hall",
                                           "N/hme-on street") ~ 2,
                          V4024 %in% c("Frn/hme-yard etc","Frn/hme-on str",
                                       "Frn/hme-at hme", "Frn/hme-apt hall"
                                           ) ~ 3,
                              V4024 %in% c("Comm-rest/bar","Other comm bld",
                                           "Gas station", "Office", "Bank",
                                           "Factory/warehouse") ~ 4,
                                V4024 %in% c("Park-apt etc",
                                             "Park-parking etc") ~ 5,
                                 V4024 %in% c("Schl-school bldg", 
                                              "Schl-school prop") ~ 6,
                                V4024 %in% c("Park-noncomm","Open-on street",
                                             "Open-pub transp",
                                             "Open-apt yd etc") ~ 7,
                                  V4024 %in% c("Other-other") ~ 8))
mutate (locale = as.factor(locale)) %>%
  mutate(locale = fct_recode(as.factor(locale), 
                             "Victim's Home" = "1", "Near Victim's Home" = "2", 
                             "At or Near friends/acq" = "3",
                             "Commercial Place" = "4",
                             "Parking lot/Garage" = "5",
                             "School" = "6", "Open Areas/Public Transport" = "7",
                             "Other" = "8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why the error occurs but I think you are taking a long route to achieve your desired output. Why not assign relevant `fct_recode` output in `case_when` directly?

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(locale = factor(case_when (V4024 %in% c("R/hme-own dwell",
                                        "R/hme-det bldg","R/home-vac/2nd", 
                                        "R/hme-htl/mtl") ~ "Victim's Home",
                           
                           V4024 %in% c("N/hme-own yrd", "N/hme apt hall",
                                  "N/hme-on street") ~ "Near Victim's Home",
                           V4024 %in% c("Frn/hme-yard etc","Frn/hme-on str",
                                        "Frn/hme-at hme", "Frn/hme-apt hall"
                           ) ~ "At or Near friends/acq",
                           V4024 %in% c("Comm-rest/bar","Other comm bld",
                                        "Gas station", "Office", "Bank",
                                   "Factory/warehouse") ~ "Commercial Place",
                           V4024 %in% c("Park-apt etc",
                               "Park-parking etc") ~ "Parking lot/Garage",
                           V4024 %in% c("Schl-school bldg", 
                                        "Schl-school prop") ~ "School",
                           V4024 %in% c("Park-noncomm","Open-on street",
                                       "Open-pub transp",
                            "Open-apt yd etc") ~ "Open Areas/Public Transport",
                           V4024 %in% c("Other-other") ~ "Other")))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! Im new to this! How do I combine case_when and fct_recode? Do I have to do as.factor first?

Comment: @MariTereMolinet You don't need `fct_recode` here. If you want to turn `locale` to `factor` you can do that outside `case_when`. See updated answer.